# How do I enable wildcard subdomains?

Tags: ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I have a website with a root domain and over 5 single-level sub-domains. For example, secure.mysite.com, checkout.mysite.com, etc. I want to install a Wildcard SSL certificate from the Apache web server. How I can install/enable subdomains? please give me the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well. First, your certificate CSR need to have a wildcard entry so when you get your cert back and sign to you, it support that.

For your Apache config, your virtualHost need to have *.mydomain.com and it will answer all the subdomain request you support.

Also, your DNS need to be correctly setup to point all your subdomain to the correct IP of your Apache server.